# Error in Crontab

Tags: linux, crontab

```
10 45  * * 1-3 changeExtension.sh
```

When i am saving this particular file i am getting the following error:-

> crontab: installing new crontab
>   "/tmp/crontab.eel6sL":1: bad hour
>   errors in crontab file, can't install.
>   Do you want to retry the same edit?

I am able to schedule the job for root user but when i am trying for other user I am getting this error. Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format starts with

```
minute hour …
```

so probably you want

```
45 10 …
```

See [`man 5 crontab`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).